# Automatically dissolving edges in quad faces that share same normals

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, text-object

Good morning,

I'm trying to getting from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Is there an automatic way to limited dissolve all only square adjacent surfaces of a mesh into few only squares surfaces (or rectangular surfaces).

**Situation:**
The fact is I had a text object, then limited dissolved for having n-gon only surfaces, then applied remesh for have square only surfaces. Now I have too many useless square surfaces that I think can be collapsed in few ones.

**What I need**
The point is, I want a meshed extruded text to have as few as possible quadrangular surfaces, without altering its perimeters (only collapse same angle quadrangular adjacent surfaces int as few as possible bigger quadrangular surfaces).

**Already tried**
I've already tried the remesh modifier, but it only messes up the border of my text mesh.

Hope I make myself clear in my explanation.

Thank everyone for any answers

Comment: Welcome to BSE, Are you looking to a fully automated way, because it's possible to select faces with similar normals, then you can dissolve the edges using that selection, but of course some manual work will still be required.

Comment: Can you try to enhance the format of your text a little, specially the title?

Comment: Have you looked into the decimate modifier with yhe "planar" option, it won't create quads but it can collapse edges of planar faces within a certain threshold. Maybe it's a good starting point.

Comment: @Georges - 1) the title, as you modified it now is not explaining my question: I asked to "collapse same angle quadrangular adjacent surfaces into as few as possible bigger quadrangular surfaces" which is different from your version "dissolving edges in quad faces that share same normals" (in this case, the faces I'm getting could also be n-gons), please, edit the title back to original - 2) if I select faces with similar normals, like you said, and then dissolve the edges of this selection, I could also obtain n-gons ... that is not what I want: I want to get only quadrangular faces.

Comment: I edited the title because it was unclear, if you check the image that you attached, the results you want are Ngons! It doesn't matter if they look square, they have more than 4 vertices, so they are Ngons. I asked that you edit your format before SUGGESTING edit, the edit were approved by other moderators. I believe you can still edit your question and title.

Comment: #Georges ... you are right, thank you for the explanation of "It doesn't matter if they look square, they have more than 4 vertices, so they are Ngons" ... thank you again. So, maybe is that my question is not possible answerable at all? (due to the impossibility of translating a mesh with curve perimeters into bigger-and-little quadrangular surfaces only)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos ... thank you for your advice, I've tried as you said, to use decimate modifier with planar option: anyway, adjusting the angle value to more than or equal to 10°, it just deform the mesh. Using it with < 10° as per angle value, it just create n-gons, which is the situation where it started all (after I've Text -> Mesh -> Limited Dissolve and before Remesh) ... anyway, thank you for your consideration

Comment: @MAries I really don't know an automated way to do that, if I knew I would post it in an answer. Besides, it all depends on your mesh, try uploading your .blend file, may be someone can help provide an automated or at least an easy manual way to do it, you can upload your file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Do you really need quadrangular faces or simply to lower the vertices amount keeping the exact same external shape ?

Comment: @lemon ... it's not a must, but I want to know how to do it. Or if it is not possible. Thank you

Comment: @Georges ... this is the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2t6C4o5L_DjdjVoMjJ2cXlHSTg

Comment: There are lot's of variations, each character has it's own shape, and curvature makes it even harder, so I don't think there's an automatic way to apply this to all characters with the same parameters, I could be wrong, if there's a way I would like to know about, yet it's doable in a semi automated way, reducing the mesh significantly without changing the contour, then connecting few vertices manually to get all faces to be quads. May be if you can explain what's the purpose of the procedure (why are you looking for this specific results) there could be other workarounds possible. @MAries

Comment: @Georges ... Thankyou ... my goal is to have a mesh (turned from text) which is lowest-ploy possible without impacting text-font-shape (that is to reduce rendering time) ... and the quad shape faces, I wanted them because I've read that many game rendering engines works much faster with quad-gone surfaces and so I want to learn Blender using quad-gones as much as possible

Comment: @MAries Quads, Tris and Ngons are just the way computer show you the object's structure in view port, Quads are easier to "work" with, this is concerning user experience, while computer actually treats everything as Tris, since it's more accurate to calculate a surface using 3 points, rather than 4.
3 points will guarantee a flat surface, I researched this matter before, and most of the answers where that this is a myth, game engines will always treat your mesh as Tris, no matter how you build them in your 3D software.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution that lower the mesh vertices but does **not keep the quads**.

- Join the two shapes (to work both on 'Marco' and 'Aries'). For that select them both in object mode, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- Go to edit mode and delete the bottom faces vertices, so that you keep only the top faces

At this step you have the exact same shape, except it is flat :
[image]

- Go to object mode
- Convert to curve <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then "curve from mesh/text"

You obtain this (no faces) :

[image]

- Go to the properties panel and in the curve tab, then click on 2D

[image]

This makes the faces reappear :
[image]

Now to regive volume. Convert again to mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> then "Mesh from curve/.../text")

The inner mesh is the following :
[image]

You can now extrude it again to regive the original volume.

**So no quads**. But starting with 41 402 vertices, you now have 8 080. And the shape is the same.

Comment: @MAries : i know you probably started with a text which is similar to the curve version I propose here... but I hope this proposal helps to move things...

Comment: *Limited Dissolve* will make that much faster and simpler.

Comment: ok @MrZak... this answer was just about going on as no one gives a way...

Comment: @lemon ... thank youo for your consideration and for your answer. Even if I meant to obtain quad surfaces for the mesh, it gave me hints on the reversal way to handle such "once-text" mesh. I appreciate it

Comment: @MrZak ... yeah, "limited dissolve" is what I've used in the process: "text" -> convert from curve to mesh -> limited dissolve (obtained n-gons) -> remesh modifiers (obtained 4-gons .. but too much ;) ) ... thank you also for your consideration

Comment: ... as I've already stated in one of my comments to my request, as Georges pointed out to me "It doesn't matter if they look square, they have more than 4 vertices, so they are Ngons". So, maybe is that my question is not possible answerable at all (due to the impossibility of translating a mesh with curve perimeters into bigger-and-little quadrangular surfaces only)